# WordPress single product page show price according to my Requirements But code is not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have written a code for wordpress single product page in which i want to show price of product according to my requirments but when i put the code in function.php my site went down and shows internal server error. but it was working fine before the woocommerce update. 
here is output snapshot when it was working fine.
[CODE OUT PUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yolcI.png)
thanks in advance for help.
Here is my Code:

```
function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    global $product; $woocommerce;
        if($product->get_type()=='simple') {

        $percentage = round( ( $product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price() * 100 ).'%';
        $dollars='$'.($product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price());
            $percentage_txt = __(' You Save: ', 'woocommerce' ).$dollars.'('.$percentage.')';
        return '<del>'.'Price: ' . wc_price( $regular_price ) . '</del><br> <ins>' .'Sale Price: '. wc_price( $sale_price )  . '</ins><br><span style="color:red">'.$percentage_txt.'</span>';
    }

    else if($product->get_type()=='variable'){

        $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        $count = count($available_variations)-1;
                $variation_id=$available_variations[$count]['variation_id'];        
                $variable_product1= new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );
                $regular_price = $variable_product1 ->get_regular_price();
                $sale_price = $variable_product1 ->get_sale_price();
                $percentage = round( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price * 100 ).'%';
            $dollars='$'.($regular_price - $sale_price);
            $percentage_txt = __(' You Save: ', 'woocommerce' ).$dollars.'('.$percentage.')';
        return '<del>'.'Price: ' . wc_price( $regular_price ) . '</del><br> <ins>' .'Sale Price: '. wc_price( $sale_price )  . '</ins><br><span style="color:red">'.$percentage_txt.'</span>';
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Do your server logs tell you where a failure occurred?

Comment: no i cant see any error in error log

Comment: Change `global $product; $woocommerce;` to `global $product, $woocommerce;` or remove simply `$woocommerce;` as your code doesn't need it…

Comment: Thanks for your help.
i have changed the code as you said but this didn't work for me